# Eloquent pre-loading relationships against DB write connection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, database-replication

I have a Laravel 5.2 project with a DB master-slave setup. When running something like `Model::onWriteConnection()->with('relationship')->find($id)`, only the `find()` query is run against the write connection; the `with()` query is still run against a slave.

This particular query **must** be run against the master connection, since the relevant data may not have been replicated to the slaves yet.

Is there a way to force all parts of the eloquent query to run against the write connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
Model::onWriteConnection()->with(['relationship'=>function($query){
   $query->useWritePdo();
}])->find($id)
```

look at [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

Comment: Smart! I didn't think of trying to use eager load constraints in this manner. However, onWriteConnection() is not defined on the QueryBuilder; but useWritePdo() is, and it does seem to work! Thanks!