# Laravel / Illuminate's useWritePdo not being respected when loading relationships

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, illuminate-container

I'm trying to force my application to use the write connection when running a select because of race conditions dealing with updating the data and refreshing it. I have confirmed that useWritePdo() function is being called, but I can tell it's not using the write connection because the race condition bug still exists. I don't know how to determine through var dumps whether the write connection is being used.

Here is the code I'm running, followed by the involved models. Note that forcing the write connection works if I call $portfolio->items($useWriteConn), but not $user->portfolios($useWriteConn)->with('items').

```
return $this->user->portfolios($useWriteConn)->with('items')->find($id);
```

Model User.php:

```
namespace App;

use App\Notifications\ResetPassword;
use App\Support\Auth\RetrievesUser;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

/**
 * Class User
 * @package App
 * @property integer $subscription
 * @property integer $id
 */
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword, UserTrait, Notifiable, HasApiTokens, RetrievesUser


    public function portfolios($useWriteConn = false)
    {
        return ($useWriteConn) 
            ? $this->hasMany(UserPortfolio::class, 'user')->writeConn()
            : $this->hasMany(UserPortfolio::class, 'user');
    }
}
```

Model UserPortfolio.php

```
namespace App;

// use App\UserCustomViews;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class UserPortfolio extends Model 
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user');
    }

    public function items($useWriteConn = false, $showClosed = true)
    {
        $items = $this->hasMany(UserPortfolioItem::class, 'portfolio');

        if ($useWriteConn)
            $items->writeConn();
        if (!$showClosed)
            $items->open();

        return $items;
    }

    public function scopeWriteConn($query)
    {
        return $query->useWritePdo();
    }
}
```

Model UserPortfolioItem.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class UserPortfolioItem extends Model 
{

    public function portfolio()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(UserPortfolio::class, 'portfolio');
    }

    public function scopeWriteConn($query)
    {
        return $query->useWritePdo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this later, I found the answer in another thread.

[Eloquent pre-loading relationships against DB write connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347718/eloquent-pre-loading-relationships-against-db-write-connection/39348088#39348088)

```
Model::onWriteConnection()->with(['relationship'=>function($query){
   $query->useWritePdo();
}])->find($id)
```